# the relation between agent pool size(num_poolagents) and worker agents and coordinating agents in IBM DB2 (LUW)

Tags: db2-luw

I am going to configure the size of agents pool in IBM DB2, the default size is Automatic(100). As I understand there are coordinator agents which responsible to connection to clients(remote application or local clients). Also, There are worker agents where handle requests from applications and assigned by coordinators. The default value of Maximum Number of Coordinating agents is set to Automatic(200) which means maximum number of connected applications.
The question is that is the sum of coordinating agents and worker agents is equal to num_poolagents?I mean if I set Num_poolagents to 100, the sum of coordinating agents and worker agents will not exceed 100?

I run db2 get database manager configuration and see the default values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoPuU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between [max_coordagents](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-max-coordagents-maximum-number-coordinating-agents) and [num_poolagents](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-num-poolagents-agent-pool-size).
You may think about `num_poolagents` as a number of apples on a shelf. If there are no more apples there, a shop manager can bring you a number of apples needed from a store.

Comment: thank you, suppose you set num_poolagents to 100. and currently you have 50 connections which occupy 50 coordinating agents. Also, 25 worker agents are handling requests. are remaining agents from pool is 25?

Comment: This may depend on previous activity & [num_initagents](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-num-initagents-initial-number-agents-in-pool) setting. You start with `num_initagents`. Up to `num_poolagents - num_initagents` new agents may be created but not destroyed, when they become idle. So, you may have 0-25 idle agents in the pool in your case.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, As I have send the default setting of DB2 in question, the default value of MAX_COORAGENT is set to 200 and NUM_POOLAGENTS is set to 100. would you please let me know why they configure in this way? number of coordinating agent may exceed number of pool agents.

Comment: Sure it can. When all pool agents are associated with connections, and new connection is created, then the following happens. A new agent is created (with all the corresponding initialization steps like memory allocations, etc). It starts working on behalf of this connection. Finally, this agent is destroyed (with memory deallocation, etc), when the connection ends, because the pool is full of other agents. The reason of such a configuration is probably a balance between speed of agent-to-connection association and memory use for a large number of rarely used agents.

Answer (score 0):

The agent pool is used to avoid frequent process kills and creations. If an agent gets idle it can wait in the pool for a new request - avoiding the overhead of destroying it and creating a new process if needed.

Also check out the helpful page about the [Db2 process model](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=architecture-db2-process-model)

Agent processes will only get destroyed if the pool is already full of idle agents.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but my question is that what is the relation between number of coordinating agents and worker agent and num_poolagents?